# How to recursively delete the contents of all "node_modules" directories (or any dir), starting from current directory, leaving an empty folder?

Tags: bash, command-line, files, recursive

Suppose I have a directory structure like this:

```
projects/
  project1/
    src/
    node_modules/
      dir1/
      dir2/
      dir3/
      file
  project2/
    node_modules/
      dir4/
```

Starting from `projects/` I want to delete the contents of all `node_modules/` directories, but I do not want to delete the `node_modules/` itself, leaving it empty, without folders or files inside.

In the example above the items `dir1`, `dir2`, `dir3`, `file` and `dir4` would be deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following will delete all files and directories within a path matching `node_modules`:

```
find . -path '*/node_modules/*' -delete
```

If you would like to check what will be deleted first, then omit the `-delete` action.